# Почему не работает составной ключ в Asp.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

Обновляю Asp.net MVC на Core

```
public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("Virtual_KEY")]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public string Id2 { get; set; }
```

> Entity type 'Client' has composite primary key defined with
>   data annotations. To set composite primary key, use fluent API.

Comment: Так вот же и ответ - составной ключ через Fluent API задается

Comment: так он формируется автоматически  и после обновления моделей изменения потеряются? Больше через Column(Order работать не будет?

Comment: к сожалению у Core есть свои ограничения

Comment: а где прочитать почему изменили?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В тот класс, который является у Вас наследником DbContext, нужно добавить такой метод:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
        .HasKey(c => new { c.Id, c.Id2 });
}
```

Например:

```
    public class ApplicationContext : DbContext {
        public DbSet<Client> clientItem { get; set; }

        public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
            : base(options) {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            modelBuilder.Entity<TuGroupItem>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.GroupId, c.TuId });
        }
    }
```